# Hide button on videojs play()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a play button inside of a video js video / container and I would like the button to hide(), when the video plays. It works if I just use $('.video-play-btn).hide() on the play function but the problem is I have numerous videos on the page so it is hiding them all, I only want the video that is being played for the button to hide.

html:

```
   <div class="col-lg-6">
        <video-js data-video-id="6563228568228"
                  data-embed="default"
                  data-application-id=""
                  class="video-js video-container--outer full-width"
                  controls
                  id=""
                  webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"></video-js>
        <!-- play button -->
        <button class="video-play-btn btn"><i class="fa fa-play fa-play-video-inline"></i></button>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
var videoPlayer = videojs('video-one');

 videoPlayer.on('play', function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.video-play-btn').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do give the button id which is the video id with some prefix or suffix,on play function get the ID of video and embed suffix or prefix and hide that button.
In the below example **v_6563228568228** is video id and **btn_v_6563228568228** is the button id that is same as video id with prefix of **btn_**.This way you can provide unique id to your button.

Example.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
          <video
    id="v_6563228568228"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="https://mobamotion.mobatek.net/samples/sample-mp4-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>
  <button class="video-play-btn btn" id="btn_v_6563228568228"><i class="fa fa-play fa-play-video-inline"></button>
    </div>

  <script>
  var videoPlayer = videojs('v_6563228568228');

 videoPlayer.on('play', function () {
        vid_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#btn_"+vid_id).hide();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! this will work, yes. However I have numerous videos on this page. I"m more wondering why I cannot navigate the DOM and hide each videos button on that given video when it plays. The funny thing is if I use a click event on the video container it works however it does not work on mobile which led me to try this route and hide on "play"